# compare Three different numbers and return 3 different words

Tags: excel

```
  A         B    C   D
1 George    3    5   4
2 Andreas   5    2   5
3 Smith     4    7   1
```

I want to find the minimum number and return a word. Sheet 1 is George Sheet 2 is Andreas sheet 3 is Smith. If George has the minimum from Andreas and Smith (e.g. 3) i want to return to different sheet e.g. sheet 4 the Name "George QW".

Comment: cell functions should be able to handle that.  what have you tried?

Comment: I know how to compare 2 differents numbers with "if" if i have different sheets e.g. if('Sheet1'!B1<'Sheet2'!B2) if true return "George" if false return "Andreas". But i can't use "if" because it doesn't give me three parameters not only true or false.

Comment: From what you've drawn, it looks like these are all on **one sheet** in columns A,B, C & D and rows 1,2 & 3, but you're mentioning different sheets in your explanation... Can you please explain how the data is actually laid out?

Comment: Sheet 1: Cell A1 George cell B1 3. Sheet 2: Cell A2 Andreas cell B2 5. Sheet 3: Cell A3 Smith B3 4. Sheet 4: I want the minimum price but doesn't write the price but a word e.g. "GeorgeQW".Don't see  the first question. I don't know how i can put 3 sheets to the quwstion for this reason you see it like one sheet.

Comment: You can use logical addititves and you can nest if calls as well.  if(AND(OR(A1=A2,A2=A3),B4=B1),if(B2=B3,"#1","#2"),"#3")

Answer (score 0):

May not be what is wanted, but the data array (including A,B,C,D column labels) from each of the three sheets could be combined into a PivotTable (say starting in A1 on Sheet 4) and in that sheet:

```
=INDEX(A:A,MATCH(MIN(B:B),B:B,0))&" QW"
```